# Characters affected by mysqli::prepare

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Maybe I'm simply over looking it, but I'm trying to find documentation showing ALL of the characters that are affected by mysqli::prepare and what the effect is on each character.

I know the common \', \", etc, but I'm assuming there are some less common characters that get escaped or encoded and I'm curious what they are.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: prepare is not an escaping function, that's the beauty of it. Instead the instructions (the sql) and the data are sent to the DB separately so it doesn't confuse the two.  Escaping may be done when the data is put in the DB, but it's not really proper to say that Prepare escaped it.

Comment: How the values are passed to the DB is an implementation detail. Such details are rarely documented. If you really need to know it, you can look into the source code.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I never considered the data was segregated from the query itself. I assumed that prepare was doing something more like escaping the parameters and then concatenating everything together.